# [iOS][Swift] Creating layout for news application content programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I want to create simple iOS application which allow users see newest news from my website. I want to have similar layout:

[Layout Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8klN3.jpg)

News will be downloaded from my website by swift.

I'm starting my adventure with Swift and iOS, and I'm not sure what should I use to create layout for news content. On Android, I created few linear layouts [vertical and horizontal] and it was very easy - in iOS I'm lost.

Should I use constraints for every components (view for content of news and UIImage, UILabels, UIButton in therein) or custom UITableView?

I don't know which solution is the best. Additionally, is iOS has some container, which has auto-height option? When I'm adding some UI elements to View, they are visible, but View Height is zero without setting it manually...

If you are able to steer me to solution, I will be very thankful... I'm so sorry for my English, but I hope that you will understand me and I very believe on your help.

Kindly Regards,
Eva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using ui UITableView with custom view cells in swift. Refer to [this link](http://shrikar.com/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/) and [this one](https://www.weheartswift.com/swifting-around/)  or [this lovely video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=adP2dG_C1XU)

Comment: @Eva you are well come let me know if you need more help. Don't forget to vote and thick if that was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView with custom tableview cells.